# How can show (*) besides the label only for input required..?

Tags: javascript, html, css, required

How can show (*) beside the label only for input required field..? 
required is not a class in my case..?

i have tried like this but not working

```css
input[required] label:after { content:" (*)";color:red; }
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" required>
</div>
    

<br>

<div>
    <label>Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="address" >
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just put (*) in your label? You can even put a span around it and style like you want.

Comment: i have already built in code many places i cant keep `star` in so many pages so that is the reason I'm looking to append from CSS

Comment: isn't it `input:required`

Comment: your css selects a label that is the *child* of the input (ie the html of <label> would have to be inside the input element).

Comment: Your current markup places the `input` after the `label` - you cannot target previous elements with CSS. You will need to change your HTML

Comment: @FastSnail input[required] works as well since it finds all the inputs with an attribute called required.

Comment: See [is there a previous sibling css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed you could also try to achieve the same with a Javascript/jQuery script that finds the required inputs and changes the labels so that you don't need to change your markup.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with jQuery so that you don't need to change your markup.
So after the page loads you can do like this

```
$('input[required]').prev('label').append('*');
```

To be able to customize the asterisk you can do this:

```
$('input[required]').prev('label').append('<font class="requiredAsterisk">*</font>');

/* And customize it in your CSS */
font.requiredAsterisk{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Its awesome.! how can i give color to it.?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```css
.wrapper > div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

input:required + label::before{
  content: "* "
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name" required>
    <label>Name:</label><br>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="address" >
    <label>Address:</label><br>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbe1k4ay/

Comment: Not sure if OP wants to alter the HTML?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible otherwise using css only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
jQuery("[required]").prev('label').append("<span>*</span>");
```

```css
label{
  display:block;
}
label span{
  color:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" required>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use css like

```css
label:has(+input:required):after {
  content: ' *';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>Address</label>
<input required >
```